# Create an unlabeled instance in Weka without using DenseInstance Class

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I have the following method, I need a new unlabeled instance. I have latest weka.jar file, but it doesn't have DenseInstance class. So how to create such an instance?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("ads.txt");

        Instances data = new Instances(datafile);
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

        Classifier ibk = new IBk();
        ibk.buildClassifier(data);

        // here need a new unlabeled instance
        double classif = ibk.classifyInstance(data.firstInstance());
        System.out.println(classif);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the recent version of the weka.jar file? Weka 3.6 does not provide a weka.jar file in the installation directory with the DenseInstance class, 3.7 (developer version) does.